# HttpWebRequest doesn't seem to "get" my proxy credentials

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, httpwebrequest, http-proxy

I have a REST-based web service I'm trying to connect to, and while it works just fine from my local dev machine, I am trouble getting it to work on my client's test system which is behind a web proxy.

I have this code snippet here:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(targetUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

if (request == null)
   return;

request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/json";

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mytopsecretpassword");

WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("myproxy.net", 8080)
         {
             Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mytopsecretpassword"),
             UseDefaultCredentials = false
         };

request.Proxy = webProxy;
```

But when I try to execute this call and get back the response like this:

```
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I keep getting an error:

> System.Net.WebException
>   The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

WTF ?!?! I'm setting up my proxy and I'm providing the proxy credentials.... what more can I do?

Comment: Checking the obvious first: Are you sure the user name and password are correct?

Comment: @dtb: yes - they work just fine when I log into the management GUI in MS IE. Also: from my local dev machine, without proxy, those credentials work just fine.

Comment: Does the proxy have an error log that you could look at? (Your code isn't obviously wrong, so it's quite difficult to debug your program remotely.)

Comment: @dtb: I have no idea - this remote system (starting at the proxy) is beyond my reach. If there *is* a proxy log, I wouldn't know about it and I don't have any access to it, either....

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler/Wireshark to look at the two HTTP requests and check if there is a difference between MSIE and HttpWebRequest?

Comment: @dtb: unfortunately, due to the same circumstances as above, I have neither Fiddler nor Wireshark, nor can I install any of those tools on that test server :-(

Comment: @marc_s is your `targetUrl` inside client network? then try using `new WebProxy("http://myproxy.net:8080/",true)`

Comment: @Damith you can also set [`BypassProxyOnLocal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.bypassproxyonlocal.aspx) in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the domain to the proxy credentials.

I'd also try setting UseDefaultCredentials = false *before* you set the new credentials.